# SQL LIMIT by end of the month

Tags: php, sql, limit

I have some code with me:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM palash ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 31";
```

I want the `LIMIT 31` to be `LIMIT END OF THE MONTH`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM palash 
WHERE your_date_column <= '2015-01-31'
ORDER BY id DESC`

Comment: Thank you but I want it to be automatic for every month

Comment: Do you mean LIMIT = 28, 29, 30 or 31 depending on current month (and year), or do you mean the number of remaining days, LIMIT 11 today?

Comment: Depending on the current month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`LAST_DAY()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day).

> Takes a date or datetime value and returns the corresponding value for
>   the last day of the month. Returns NULL if the argument is invalid.

```
mysql> SELECT LAST_DAY('2003-02-05');
        -> '2003-02-28'
mysql> SELECT LAST_DAY('2004-02-05');
        -> '2004-02-29'
mysql> SELECT LAST_DAY('2004-01-01 01:01:01');
        -> '2004-01-31'
mysql> SELECT LAST_DAY('2003-03-32');
        -> NULL
```

In your case do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM palash 
WHERE your_date_column <= LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Avoid solutions like OlivierH's (no offense, Olivier). Functions applied on your columns make it impossible for MySQL to use an index.

Comment: Will this automatically change for every month (or year)

Comment: As you can see I gave it the argument `CURDATE()`, wich is short for current date. So it will give you the date of last day of the current month (and year).

Comment: AM i supposed to add `mysql> SELECT LAST_DAY('2003-02-05');` to my code as well

Comment: I don't know what happened but now it is not displaying the table rows

Comment: To help you I need a bit more information than that. If you don't know, how should I know?

Answer (score 0):

You can limit to current month with this conditions :

```
SELECT *
  FROM palash
 WHERE MONTH(my_date_column) = MONTH(CURDATE())
   AND YEAR(my_date_column) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

You can then adjust it to get previous dates too.

EDIT / Other way : to stay close to your original idea and to still have a full SQL solution, you can get number of days in current month with [LAST_DAY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) :

```
DAY(LAST_DAY(my_date_column))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can do it

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dates](
    [DateColumn] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO [dbo].[Dates]
           ([DateColumn])
     VALUES
           ('2015-01-04 13:00:00'),
           ('2015-01-06 13:00:00'),
           ('2015-02-05 14:00:00')
GO

----Last Day of Current Month
Declare @LastDayOfCurrentMonth datetime = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))

SELECT  *
FROM    Dates
Where DateColumn < @LastDayOfCurrentMonth
```

Comment: I'm sorry, Is this php